# How do I reset the TSA-unlocked indicator on my lock?

Tags: usa, tsa, gear

I have a Lewis N Clark combo lock that has the Travel Sentry feature that allows TSA to unlock it.  The lock also has a feature that lets you know if TSA opened it - the TSA keyhole at the bottom will pop out if a TSA key is used to unlock it.

On a recent trip, TSA opened my luggage (apparently having a huge stack of tourist brochures will trigger an inspection), and the TSA keyhole on the lock was popped out:

[image]

I am not able to figure out how to reset the indicator.  I have tried pushing it in with the lock in various states of locked/unlocked with correct/incorrect combos.  Even with the lock in the combo-reset mode, I cannot push the indicator back in.

Does anyone know how I can reset the indicator?

Comment: If you crossed a national boundary, it may have been Customs, *or even immigration looking for evidence of a non-tourist intent*.

Comment: It was a domestic flight.

Comment: What does it matter who it was?

Comment: Note: I had thought "TSA007" was the model number of the lock, but I just found out [that is not the case](https://www.travelsentry.org/us/qapost/number-lock-means-tsa001-tsa002-tsa003-tsa007/).  It tells TSA which key to use to open the lock (they have several different key types).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The [Swissgear TSA lock instruction manual](https://www.swissgear.com/media/files/swissgear-tsa-lock-instructions.pdf) has some guidance on how to reset the red indicator:

> ## To reset & hide the red indicator:
>
> To return the red color indicator back to its original hidden position,
>   simply push it back into the lock body with a small pin-like device,
>   such as a paper clip. The TSA color indicator is now reset.

Tho
The OP says:

> my lock doesn't have a pinhole as shown in that manual. However, it does have a small metal plate in the keyhole that can be pushed with a pin. I was able to reset it that way.

As shown in the photo from the OP saying how his lock looks:

[image]

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/99698/discussion-on-answer-by-daniil-how-do-i-reset-the-tsa-unlocked-indicator-on-my-l).

Comment: It doesn't require the correct combination? So the TSA can reset it if they want? Seems like that significantly decreases the utility.

Answer (score 5):

On some of them, you unlock and turn the shackle 180° like you are going to reset it. But, instead of pushing the shackle in, you pull up and it will reset the indicator.